# Как работать с камерами-онайн

Tags: java, android

Я хочу создать мобильное приложение, где можно будет смотреть онлайн трансляции с web-камер,которые уже установление в городах и которые находятся в открытом доступе.

Не могу найти сервис с API, для того, чтобы я смог работать?

Может подскажите такой сервис?

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что такой сервис вообще существует? Да, есть **различные** сайты, которые транслируют видео с камер в онлайне, но в большинстве своем, **они не имеют API**.

Answer (score 2):

Если камера публичная скорее всего она (ну или медиасервер) шлют rtsp или rtmp поток в плеер на том сайте где вы эту камеру смотрите. Загляните в исходный код страницы и попытайтесь выдернуть адрес камеры оттуда.  обычно это что то типа `rtmp://195.245.10.45/web/stream_hd` А такого что бы прям апи ды еще и всех камер в городе/стране/планете - такого нет, да.